# Android - SQLiteException: near "=": syntax error (code 1)

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-cursor

I am trying to log id from users table and jobname from jobs table using user id

```
String select = "SELECT jobname FROM " + TABLE_JOBS+ "where userid =" +myid;
```

Comment: In your table TABLE_JOBS 'userid' is of integer type?

Comment: white space is missing before the "where userid="+myid;
instead use " where userid="+myid;

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> "SELECT jobname FROM " + TABLE_JOBS+ "where userid =" +myid;
> ```

You need whitespace between identifiers such as your table name and keywords such as `where`:

```
"SELECT jobname FROM " + TABLE_JOBS+ " where userid =" +myid;
```

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a whitespace before the `where` clause, so it gets appended directly to the table name, and you effectively don't have a `where` clause:

```
String select = "SELECT jobname FROM " + TABLE_JOBS+ " where userid =" +myid;
// whitespace was missing here -----------------------^
```